What is the purpose of the food motifs in Macbeth Act 4 scene 1?
For example, the following lines:

Against the churches, though the yeasty waves
Confound and swallow navigation up,
Through bladed corn be lodged and trees blown down,
Though castles topple on their warders' heads.


Welcome to LitSE. This is an interesting question but as it stands it's not entirely clear what, specficically, you are asking about. It would be very helpful if you could find some more examples of food-related motifs and metaphors in the text that you are curious about?

It's not quite a food motif going on there--"yeasty" here means "frothy" or "unsettled" rather than "full of yeast", and "corn" is a generic term for grain crops (mostly in the UK). Notice that he also talks about trees being blown down and buildings collapsing. It's more of a collection of dire consequences. Macbeth is here demanding that the witches answer his questions regardless of what happens.

Looking online, "Though bladed corn be lodged" means that the immature grain is flattened before it is mature enough to be eaten, thus possibly leading to famine. It's not just a food motif — it's another disaster, along with trees being blown down and castles toppling.
The OED provides definitions for these:

bladed: Enclosed in the blade, not yet in full ear.
lodged: To throw down on the ground, lay flat. Now only of rain or wind: To beat down crops.

